# Facebook Comment Box doesn't expand its container div

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I've embedded a Facebook Comment box into my site (http://ponycountdown.com), but the `div` it is contained within doesn't expand to accommodate it. Does anyone know what causes this, and if there is a way around it?

To see the problem in action, click the comments tab on the left of that page.

An additional query - is it possible to reverse the order of comments so that the most recent is on top? I tried adding reverse="true", but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Where is the problem on the site? I don't see it...

Comment: Click "view 3 more" in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height` of the div to `min-height` in CSS.

In other words, use `min-height: 392px` instead of `height: 392px`.

This way it will expand and not be of fixed height as it is now. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's already set to min-height. Originally I had no height declaration at all, which in theory should keep it at the height of the comments box, but it doesn't. I'm going to remove the min-height attribute now, just to give a better idea of the problem for people.

Edit: Hang on, where are you getting that 392 from? That's nowhere in my code.

Comment: Its working perfectly for me if I change `height` to `min-height` in CSS.

Comment: This worked for me... The `div` has an inner style which sets its `height` to `392px`

Comment: Where in the CSS? I don't have height explicitly declared anywhere in it.

Comment: The `div` with the following classes applied to it: `slide-out-div open`. In there, it has `style="line-height: 1; position: absolute; height: 392px; top: 100px; left: -3px;"`. Change `height: 392px;` to `min-height: 392px`.

Comment: I Advise you to use chrome to check out your website, It's very easy to view HTML,CSS and Javascript through it's `Inspect Element` feature...

Comment: Strange, none of that is in my CSS. I'm using a jQuery library to do the sliding div, perhaps that's adding the CSS itself. I'll have a look.

Comment: Ah, any chance you can check and let me know if it's fixed? I found what should be the problem, but I think my web host is doing some caching or something, because changes aren't showing up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add the following to the `slide-out-div` class:

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

With some additional styling this will create a scrollbar when the facebook comments overflow downwards.